# Fair rolling for a six sided die

Tags: probability

One die is rolled with the following payoffs:
$$\begin{array}{c|r}
1 & \$25 \\
2 & \$5 \\
3 & \$0 \\
4 & -\$10 \\
5 & -\$10 \\
6 & -\$15
\end{array}$$
How much would I need to pay , or be paid, to make the game fair?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate or I'm afraid the question will be put on hold as "unclear what you are asking."

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Comment: Let random variable $X$ be your income from the game. Calculate $E(X)$. You should find that this is $-\frac{6}{6}$. So you should be paid $\frac{5}{6}$ to make the game fair.

Comment: A fair price for a game is one in which if you play the game many times, your expected winning/losses will equal the total price you paid to play the game.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the expected value. Each side has an equal probability, so take the average payout as your expected payout. So $E(X) = -\frac{5}{6}$. So that's how much you expect to gain. So you expect to lose $\frac{5}{6}$ units of money. That's how much you'd want to be paid.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the profit expectancy (i.e., how much you win or lose per each die-throw on average): $$\frac{25}{6}+\frac{5}{6}+\frac{0}{6}-\frac{10}{6}-\frac{10}{6}-\frac{15}{6}=-\frac{5}{6}$$

So you'll be losing $\frac{5}{6}$\$ on average, for every die-throw. Now it depends on your definition of a game. If a game includes $N$ die-throws, then you'll need to get paid $N\frac{5}{6}$\$ in order to make it fair.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you're risk-averse, risk-neutral, or risk-seeking, but if you're risk-neutral then the answer is indeed \$0.83 (rounded) since you're losing \$0.83 on average by playing this game.